# Convert char* to unsigned char arduino

Tags: c, arduino

I have a char array

`char data[] = "0123456789012345"; //16 chars == 16 bytes`

I want to send this data thru BLE shield using this method

`void ble_write(unsigned char data);`

This is my code in Arduino

`ble_write(data);`

I am getting this error `invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'unsigned char' [-fpermissive]`

What can I do to convert char* to unsigned char?

Comment: What do you mean? Into what character do you want the pointer to be converted into? `data[i]` will "convert" it into the `i`-th character of the array.

Comment: Nit: That array has 17 characters/bytes. You forgot to count the trailing NUL.

Comment: Presumably, you need to reference each character in your array in turn and pass it to the function: `char *ptr = data; while (*ptr != '\0') ble_write((unsigned char)*ptr);` — where's the catch?

Answer (score 0):

In your case you are sending a pointer to a table of chars ( char *) but the ble_write function takes as argument only a unsigned char ! so you need to first of all declare the data table as unsigned char, and then use a loop to send each element of the table ( data[i]) until you reach the null character '\0'.